# Unable to save local.properties file in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

> Unable to save
>   '/Users/Jack/Documents/project.io/app/platforms/android/local.properties'/Users/Jack/Documents/project.io/app/platforms/android/local.properties
>   (Permission denied)

I got this error in android studio when trying to import my ionic project.

Comment: What operating system? Have you checked so that the user trying to save is actually allowed to save in that directory?

Comment: @mattias mac osx. I didn't try to save, it's by android studio. I can't important the projec.

Comment: Did you ever sort this out?

Answer (score 16):

In your case doing

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /Users/Jack/Documents/project.io
```

should work

Answer (score 14):

Not sure if you fixed this already. I believe you probably repo clone the project under "sudo". So the owner of that folder will be "root".

The easy way to fix this would be to delete the directory and then re-clone without "sudo".

Answer (score 0):

run your android studio as administrator,too. It will work